# Compare three Columns and output instances of duplication

Tags: excel

I have three columns, each containing a list of email addresses that haven't opened over three consecutive email sends.

I would like a forth column to output any email addresses that appear in each of the three columns. What would be the easiest way to achieve this in Excel(2007)?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is probably a better way, but a (very) simple/quick thing you could try is first finding which column is the longest (longest by unique values - so if there are duplicates you'll want to account for that). Then, in column four (call it `D`, the others being `A:C`), you could do:

```
=IF(SUM(IF(COUNTIF(B:B,A1)>0,1,0), IF(COUNTIF(C:C,A1)>0,1,0))=2,A1,"")
```

This will show all emails that appear in all three lists (note that this will include empty spaces, so you'll have to filter the results). This works by the logic that the longest list of unique emails contains the entire possible sample space; from there, you know that if one of the values appears in both of the other lists, it is represented in all three.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check to see if an email appears in more than one column in the row, you can use:

```
=IF(A1 = B1, A1, IF(B1 = C1, B1, IF(A1 = C1, A1, "")))
```

If you want to test that the email appears in all three columns, use:

```
=IF(AND(A1=B1, A1=C1),A1,"")
```

Comment: Only issue with that approach is that it assumes that the emails will be next to each other in the data (for instance, if `email1@example.com` were in `A1` and `B2`, it wouldn't get picked up). However if that were the case in the underlying data, then I agree that yours is the way to go :)

Comment: Unfortunately this was the case.